# php : Cannot reference current's file parent's folder subdirectory!

Tags: php, parent, root

Please help!

My directory structure is this:

```
my_application
my_application/index.php
my_application/images
my_application/phpcode/my_script.php
```

I have this code in my_script.php

```
<?php
if(file_exists('../images)){
    // do something
}
```

?>

It works in wamp perfectly!!!

But when I upload it to my server (hostgator), it doesn't work.

In my server I do not upload it to root folder, but to a subfolder.

rootfolder/folder1/folder2/my_application

From what I understand, .. is in reference to the root path, not the current file.

How can I reference the current's file parent's folder images?

Sorry for my English. Please help! I'm stuck on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can simpli use `dirname($SCRIPT_FILENAME)` to reference the direcotry of your current script.

Have a look at [PHP Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) and [PHP Reserved Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) :)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanx a lot for the quick answer!!! If I use echo dirname( __FILE__ ); it returns /home/my_website/public_html/folder1/folder2/my_application/phpcode Can I use this a string path and concatenate it with another? For example $rootpath = dirname(dirname( __FILE__ )); and $newpath = $rootpath.'/images/;

Comment: Problem fixed. I feel so fool! It was a capitalization problem. I was using this code  if(file_exists('../Images)){
    // do something
}  , the images with capital I!!! Thanx anyway.

Comment: Happy for you :) To reply to your question yes, you can use concatenation with any string, also those returned by "dirname". If you find my answer usefull, please vot up or mark it as "the right one" =)